# Bold Text in TextView does not work with combination of Spanned and String

Tags: android

I have this code

```
TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.layout.myLayout);
Spanned myBold = (Html.fromHtml("<b>Test<b>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

If I do

```
text1.setText(myBold);
```

Then  `myBold` is in bold,which is ok. But when I want to add a string more, like

```
text1.setText(myBold+"bla");
```

Then the whole TextView is not bold anymore. Why does the new String "bla" affect this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the new String "bla" affect this?

Because what you are really doing is:

```java
text1.setText(myBold.toString() + "bla");
```

A `String` has no style information. A `Spanned` object does.

[Use `TextUtils.concat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#concat(java.lang.CharSequence...)) instead:

```java
text1.setText(TextUtils.concat(myBold, "bla"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A better choice would be to use a Bold [StyleSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan). In the next sample only the "hello" world will be set to bold by using such technique:

**Java:**

```
final SpannableString caption = new SpannableString("hello world");

// Set to bold from index 0 to the length of 'hello'
caption.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, "hello".length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

yourTextView.setText(caption);
```

**Kotlin:**

```
yourTextView.text = SpannableString("hello world").apply {
        // Set to bold from index 0 to the length of 'hello'
        setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, "hello".length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE))
    }
```

This would be a more optimal solution rather than using the **Html.fromHtml** technicque, as it doesn't have to go through the overhead of parsing/interpreting the HTML tags.
In addition, it allows you to combine more styles, sizes, etc, in the same [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString).